# Contol the location of a select type button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to control the location of a button in my browser, but I don't know how I can do that.

How can I change the button position?

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>


<body>
  <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">LED off</option>
    <option value="on">LED on</option>
  </select>

</body>
```

To do that I tried with `class` in Css. But it is not working. I have used

```
   .feat3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aa00dd;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 350px;
  width:130px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#FEF6F4;
  color : black;
  border: 10px solid  #111111;
  font-size: 20px;  <!--dotted ,dashed,solid ,double ,groove ,ridge ,inset,outset ,none ,hidden -->
  }
```

with in `<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" class='feat3'>` html.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Where do you want to put the button? There is a lot of ways to set the position of something in HTML/CSS, depending on what you really want to do, one would probably be better than the others.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough because you have just a select-field inside the body.
Could you please describe the exact case to us so that we can help

Comment: Perhaps worth creating an image to share, what you want to achieve.

Given the text, I could imagine, that it should sit on a side of a browser window.

Comment: Your libraries are ancient but still need https: protocol

Comment: I tried with class but it does't work for me to control the location. How can i do that.

Comment: "*How can i do that*" As the other comments have said, you need to tell us what "that" is before we can help you do it! Please explain a bit more about what you want to do, so we know what to help with.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I  added my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by bellow code ... but if it's not your request please tell me more about your request.

```css
body{
  position:relative
}
.switch-button{
  
}
.container{
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" class="switch-button">
      <option value="off">LED off</option>
      <option value="on">LED on</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

so based on your question I believe you're asking "How do I position my button?"

My answer would be:

**ANSWER 1**
Use Margin Top,Bottom,Right,Left

```
margin-top: #px;
margin-bottom: #px;
margin-right: #px;
margin-left: #px;
```

This will allow you to change the margin of a object, thus will basically **push** the element

*Downfall*

Now the down fall of this is that it is not responsive; Meaning if you shrink your browser the element would not be in the position you wanted it to be in originally

**Answer 2**

You could use top,right,bottom,left

```
top: #px;
bottom: #px;
left: #px;
right: #px;
```

Using this method you will get better/more accurate positioning of your element

*Downfall*
Same as the using margin, this technique will result in an unresponsive website

**Answer 3**

Use Percent

```
margin-top: #%;
margin-right: #%;
margin-left: #%;
margin-bottom: #%;
```

This will allow you to always have control over your element's position
Now with this method it will allow to make your website responsive

Hope that helped!